# Can i install Mac system in Windows?

Tags: macos

I have this technical question please!
I need to install MAC system in a Windows one.

A few questions:

1. Can i do that? (I read I could use VirtualBox or smth..)
2. Would I be able to run Xcode?

Comment: First, your question makes no sense ("Mac on a Windows one"... you meant Mac on a PC). And second, you can't install OS X in anything that's not Apple hardware. [It's forbidden by the license](http://store.apple.com/Catalog/US/Images/MacOSX.htm).

Comment: This isn't really a Stack Overflow type of question. You might be better answers on http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you definitely can. It's possible with both VirtualBox and VMWare Player. Google around, there's work to do.

It's been my experience that VirtualBox has some issues (e.g. clicking 'About This Mac' causes a logout). In both cases you won't have accelerated graphics. And yes you can any run XCode. I went with VMWare Player, works fine although Mountain Lion seems more laggy than Snow Leopard.

I'm not sure it's *illegal* to run a legal copy of OSX on non-Apple hardware, but the EULA doesn't allow it. (IANAL)

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to do this, but technically it's illegal. Also I don't think it's worth the trouble. You can get a used Mac mini for a couple of 100$ on ebay.

Comment: Would mac mini do the work? :O

Comment: If you're not planning to develop highly advanced 3D games with lots of graphics, sure. I recommend a model Early 2009 or newer. That will support Mountain Lion and the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: Thank you :)
I now came to know what a mac mini is :D
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but your bios need to support pcvirtualisation

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure there is a way you could, but any way that is possible, it would be completely illegal. Apple has made sure that it's not legal to use Apple products on non-Apple hardware. Corrected, it's not an actual law, just EULA doesn't allow it.

I just recommend you save up a couple of bucks and just buy a cheap Mac Mini at eBay or something like that, it would probably work better than any virtual copy of Mac OS X anyway.

Writing this from a newly bought Mac BTW.

Comment: Apple doesn't have the authority to write or enforce "a real law" in any jurisdiction on earth. What they have is a EULA, which is the same as any contract, the provisions of which may or may not be applicable under the real laws of your jurisdiction. (Note that this is assuming you are in fact alive and on earth; rumor has it that Steve Jobs did in fact get the authority to write laws in the afterlife; Heaven looks much nicer and runs much more smoothly than it used to, and there's no fan noise anymore, but make sure you're buried with a black turtleneck.)

Comment: @abarnert Oh OK, last time I checked it was a law. Could you please not downvote me (or whoever) next time? Doesn't really apply, since it's a good answer, or atleast not a bad answer.

Comment: Where exactly did you checked that said that Apple passed "a real law"? That's not how the legal system works in any country.

Comment: @abarnert Oh OK, I think I checked it a couple of years ago, only thing I remember is that it's not legal to use Apple products on non-Apple hardware, that's all I remember so... Yeah... I'm gonna change my answer. lol